# Gradient brush like heap

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, gradient

It looks like a simple question but I am struggling to produce as in image for background color of grid.

My manager needs same as it is.

So far I have tried this, but not getting background exactly same as below image with heap behind.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0" x:Key="Background">
        <GradientStop Color="#FBDEE0" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#F4B8B8 " Offset="0.570"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#F4B8B8 " Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Background="{StaticResource Background}">

</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool for the 'heap' is a radial gradient brush with very hard colour stops...

This declaration...

```
        <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5, 1.12" RadiusX="1.5" RadiusY="1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" SpreadMethod="Pad" >
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="IndianRed"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.49" Color="IndianRed"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Pink"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
```

...will produce an effect like this...

[image]

You can replace the colours with your own to produce an exact replica of the spec...

The docs for this type of brush are at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.radialgradientbrush.aspx